# What do disputed flags mean?

Tags: discussion, flagging

So quite a few of my flags recently got disputed and I am not sure what that means and why there were disputed.

Example:

[image: low quality]
Flagged as low quality

It got disputed. What does that mean and why did it get disputed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disputed flags are generally from the result of the post in the relevant review queue disagreeing with the flag you raised. In the example from the question, the post was flagged by you as a low quality post, so the post was placed in the low quality posts review queue where it was [reviewed as Looks OK](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/252447), therefore the flag is disputed.